# Recipes PDF batch extraction

Tags: wordpress

I am now working with 500 pdf recipes files, which I want to display in my website. How can I batch extract them and display information on PDF to my website? PDF has all the information for recipes. For each recipe, I need to display its description, image, ingredients, instructions, nutrition label and so on. Is there any way so that I don't need to work on it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Do these all have the same basic template for how the information is structured? This isn't really specifically a WordPress issue. One thing you can do is use Go to loop through and process all the files. I played with Go and it's incredibly fast to parse large amounts of information. Maybe you can fiddle with it in this library here https://github.com/unidoc/unidoc.

There are a lot of library options to try in PHP also. Here's just one example https://www.pdfparser.org/. There's documentation here and you can install it via composer. https://www.pdfparser.org/documentation

If every recipe follows the same sort of template, and you want to extract specific details in specific sections of the PDF, it should be easy enough. If you don't mind extracting all the text from a PDF and just display that on your website, it should be easy enough using one of the libraries. If you go the Golang route, you could just parse all the text for each PDF, save them to a file, and just upload them using PHP and have the PHP code insert everything into custom post types or something.

Comment: Thank you so much.